# Structure form creation

Tags: ms-access-2010

a quick question on creating forms.  I would like to know how to remove the what seems to be a "locked grid" on my fields when creating a form.  In essence, when i create forms, all my fields seem to be linked and when I adjust the length or width of one, they all adjust respectively making it impossible for me to tailor my form to my needs.   It seems to me that the only option around this is creating a form from scratch and inserting field by field. There must be a quick way to disactivate this feature once the fields are created within the form.
Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `Arrange` tab from the Ms Access Ribbon.

Then, when your "locked grid" is selected press:

[image]